# After building , the .exe outside the Release folder dont working

Tags: debugging, release, bin, building, launching

After building a project it appears in the Release folder. After launching it outside the release folder program will stop working. Im using MetroFramework design .dll's for sure. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other files, such as DLL files, in the release folder that your exe depends on. When you move your exe, ensure these files are in the same folder.

Comment: @johhny_hax you're welcome. If this solves the problem in your question can you mark this as the answer please?